# Send file from backbone Model to django

Tags: django, file, backbone.js, upload

I want to upload files from Backbone to Django File upload system.

First of all I've follow the https://stackoverflow.com/a/10916733/1590377 explanation. I've do a FileModel and with the above indication I have a model with this information:

```
attributes: Object
    data: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw ..."
    file: "image2012-06-12 13:36:45.png"
```

now I save the model to the URL where I have the upload view in django like this:

```
def upload_file_64(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':

       file = cStringIO.StringIO(base64.b64decode(request.POST['data']))
       #method to save the file
       response_data={"result":"ok"}
       return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_data), mimetype='application/json')
else:
    response_data={"success": "No a post request"}
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_data), mimetype='application/json')
```

but the response that the django sistem give me is:

```
"MultiValueDictKeyError at /api/upload64/↵'Key \'data\' not found in <QueryDict: {u\'base64,iVBORw0KG....
```

The POST http request is:

```
 POST:
 base64,iVBORw0KG ..."} = u''
 {"file":"Captura de pantalla de 2012-06-12 13:36:45.png","data":"data:image/png = u''
```

How I can fix this so that I can upload a file to django. I use a multi-part method to upload files from another platforms how android but with backbone I can't upload a file.

Can someone help me eith this problem?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I've coded another solution. I've used a jquery upload pluging to upload the file, and get the response.

The plugin is : http://lagoscript.org/jquery/upload/demo?locale=en and the code that I used in my backbone view is:

```
events : {
    'change #file1' : 'upload'
},
upload : function(){

    $('#file1').upload('http://192.168.0.195/api/upload/', function(res) {
            console.log(res)
            //now I use the res to create a model :)
        }, 'html');
},
```