# Convert base64 image to StringIO for Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, base64, carrierwave

I am hoping someone can help me understand this.  I have a base64 string for an image:

```
"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABA..."
```

I would like to send it using ember's createRecord and commit():

```
this.get('store').createRecord(Emb.Painting, {name: newName, image: newImage});
```

Then I want to convert it to StringIO for carrierwave and save it:

```
StringIO.class_eval { def original_filename; "stringiohaxx.jpg"; end }
io = StringIO.new(Base64.decode64(params[:painting][:image]))
@painting =  Painting.create(:name => params[:painting][:name], :image => io )
```

An image is saved. The image is always corrupted.  Do I need to break my break my base64 string into:

```
data: '/9j/..'
type: 'image/jpeg'
```

?  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you need to split the string. You could use something like this:

```
def splitBase64(uri)
  if uri.match(%r{^data:(.*?);(.*?),(.*)$})
    return {
      type:      $1, # "image/png"
      encoder:   $2, # "base64"
      data:      $3, # data string
      extension: $1.split('/')[1] # "png"
      }
  end
end
```

Then you can decode the image...

```
base64image = params[:painting][:image]
imageDataString = splitBase64(base64image)[:data]
imageDataBinary = Base64.decode64(imageDataString)
```

Then you can pass the imageDataBinary to StringIO.new() and the resulting image should be valid.

Answer (score 0):

And yes that string does need to be broken up:

```
var data = newImage.split(',');  
this.get('store').createRecord(Emb.Painting, {name: newName, image: data[1]});
```

I doubt this is the best way...

Comment: Indeed, just as the documentation states here: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html